# How to run Hadoop hive query on PHP

Tags: php, hadoop

I use hadoop for processing a lot of reports on my server.But this This is mostly done on the CLI of the server.  Is it possible to run the same queries inside a PHP code. ? So that I can schedule it to run. ?

Answer (score 3):

The standard way to run Hive queries from PHP is to use a Thrift Client. For details see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient => look for the PHP Client.

But if you really want you can also use PHP to run CLI commands, although parsing the data results will be challenging - hence the PHP Thrift Client is an easier way to go.